# Disable Google +1 functionality

Tags: google-search, google-plus-1

How do I disable [Google +1](https://web.archive.org/web/20120306001302/http://www.google.com/+1/button/) functionality from appearing in my searches?

I want to remove "+1" icon from Google Search results. Is there a way to do so?

[image: Google result with +1 button]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Download [Adblock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/en/)
2. Add filter `##button.esw`

Goodbye `Google PlusOne` icons.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Any clues what I could be doing wrong? Chrome 12.0.742.100 on OS X.

Comment: Check out with Chrome's Developers Tools what class has Google +1 Icon. Then try to replace `esw` in `##button.esw` filter for `##button.newClassFoundByYou`. (Or) If Google uses other element than button - for example `div` than replace `##button.esw` filter with `##div.esw`. (Or) Combination of these two: `##div.newClassFoundByYou`. You should simply check how is in your case.

Answer (score 2):

> Steps to Enable/ Disable Google +1
>   Button
>
> 1. Goto [Google +1 button page](http://www.google.com/+1/button/)
> 2. Click on Try now button
> 3. Now you have turned on the google +1 button.
> 4. If you want to leave or turn off google +1 then goto [Page](http://www.google.com/experimental/index.html)
> 5. Click on Leave button

[Source](http://nscraps.com/Internet/833-how-enable-disable-google-plus1.htm)

Comment: Where on [Google +1 button page](http://www.google.com/+1/button/) is `Try now` button ? @Systech:  Have you checked your solution, or have you pasted the link mindlessly ?

Comment: @Coola, I see a big "Try it now" button when I go to that page, is that not the button in question?

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CrFJR.png) is this page from my point of view.

Answer (score 2):

For Firefox users: Print and follow these steps to turn off/disable/remove Google +1 Buttons from search results with or without AdBlock or AdBlock Plus and *without* having to create a Google profile:

1. Go to Firefox Profiles folder on your hard drive.

   To locate your Firefox Profiles in Windows XP, Vista, 7:

   1. press: <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+ <kbd>R</kbd>
   2. Type in:

      > **%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles**
   3. Click OK

   or from the Taskbar:

   1. Click: START → RUN
   2. Type in:
        %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
   3. Click OK

   The Profiles Folder will open.   There will probably be only one folder in the  Profiles folder.
2. Open the folder with the  "**.default**"  extension name.
3. Look for a folder named Chrome in the .default folder. If Chrome folder does not exist, you need to create it. (If the Chrome folder exists, skip to #4).

   To create the Chrome folder:

   1. Right-click inside the .default folder
   2. Select NEW FOLDER
   3. Type in: **Chrome**
4. Open the Chrome folder and create a text file named userContent.css.  (The contents of this file tells Firefox not to display +1 Buttons on web pages.)

   To create a text file named userContent.css:

   1. Right-click inside the Chrome folder
   2. Select NEW → TEXT DOCUMENT
   3. Type in: **userContent.css**

   Windows will bring up "Rename" warning dialogue box that says:

   > If you change a file name extension, the file may become unusable. Are you sure you want to change it?
   >   Yes No

   1. Select **YES**
5. Open userContent.css.  (It will open in Notepad with a box titled:  userContent.css - Notepad).
6. Paste the following into Notepad:

   ```
   .esw { display:none!important; } /* Hides the +1 Button completely */
   ```

   Be sure to include the period (.) before "esw" in the above.
7. Save the Notepad file and Close it: Select FILE → SAVE →  FILE → CLOSE (or select X on folder title bar to Close)
8. Close remaining open folders.
9. If Firefox Browser is not closed, close it.

Re-open Firefox Browser.  Navigate to Google's search page and perform a search.  Google +1 Buttons will be gone from all future search results.

Answer (score -1):

I disabled mine by going to https://plus.google.com/+1/personalization
Hope this works for you too =)

Comment: What settings did you change within personalization?

Comment: @batpigandme for me there are only two options when i visit the link i posted. 1) **enable** 2) **disable**.